# vue prop display columns with different sizes wrapped in container

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, bulma

I'm currently working on a page for our company's new website. In this design we have a blog page which displays our blog entries. I request these blogs with Cockpit CMS & axios in my NuxtJs project that makes it a object.

At this moment I'm struggling with the following: In the design the blogs are displayed in rows of 3 items, and after that 2 items. I'm using the BULMA framework and to display my columns the correct way I need to wrap the columns like follow:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

A short version of my code can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/06o5nvkd/

At this moment I have a component which gets my blogs through a prop called 'blogs'. Me and my colleague can't find a good working method to split the blogs array into chunks of 2 & 3 to display them correctly in a wrapping columns div.

Is anyone here able to help us out? Any more information that's needed is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed property to chunk your `blogs` array on the fly and use that array with the chunks to create the columns.

Computed properties detect addtions to the `blogs` array automatically (when using `this.blogs` inside), so fetching some new blog entries will be no problem.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    blogs: [
      { title: "Learn JavaScript" },
      { title: "Learn Vue" },
      { title: "Play around in JSFiddle" },
      { title: "Build something awesome" },
      { title: "a" },
      { title: "b" },
      { title: "c" },
      { title: "d" },
      { title: "e" },
      { title: "f" },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    blogsChunked() {
      let blogs = this.blogs;
      let chunkSize = 2;
      let blogsChunked = [];
      while (blogs.length > 0) {
        let chunk = blogs.slice(0, chunkSize);
        blogs = blogs.slice(chunkSize);
        blogsChunked.push(chunk);
        chunkSize == 2 ? chunkSize++ : chunkSize--;
      }
      return blogsChunked;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

div.column {
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section class="blogs has-padding-bottom-xxl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns is-mobile" v-for="(chunk, index) in blogsChunked" :key="index">
        <div class="column" v-for="(blog, key) in chunk" :key="key">
          {{ blog.title }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have nested arrays & v-for loops.

```
<div id="app">
  <section class="blogs has-padding-bottom-xxl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns"  v-for="(blogs, key) in blogsArr" :key="key">
      <div class="column" v-for="(blog, index) in blogs" :key="index">
      {{ blog.title }}
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    blogsArr: [
      [{ title: "Learn JavaScript" },
      { title: "Learn Vue" }],
      [{ title: "Play around in JSFiddle" },
      { title: "Build something awesome" }]
    ]
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3vqydakw/

Comment: Problem with this is, is that I get my blog entries with axios in 1 single array with all my blog entries, I can't nest them as far as I know.

Comment: You can though, like done here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495740/6685348 just push the chunks into a new array. Maybe someone else has a better solution though.